# How to add a WHERE function to a complex string

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to only query data that has a number > 0 in Column K within this complex string.

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A1:K,"SELECT *" & if(COUNTBLANK('Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)=3,""," WHERE " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ",TRUE,'Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)),1)
```

I tried...

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A1:K,"SELECT * WHERE K > 0" & if(COUNTBLANK('Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)=3,""," WHERE " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ",TRUE,'Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)),1)
```

But keep getting an error.

Not sure what I need to do.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A1:K, 
 "where K > 0"&IF(COUNTBLANK('Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)=3,,
 " and "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 'Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)), 1)
```

Comment: Oh looks like you removed the "WHERE *" and replaced it with the correct command.

Comment: @AustinFarmer sure, `the SELECT *` is unnecessary so skip that. in one query formula can be only one `where`. after that you need to either use `and` or `or`

Answer (score 0):

The second formula has two `WHERE`s.  Replace the second one with `AND`, something like:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A1:K,"SELECT * WHERE K > 0" & if(COUNTBLANK('Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)=3,""," AND " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ",TRUE,'Helper Formulas'!A1:A3)),1)
```

You may need to tweak this if you end up with too many "AND"s.

When troubleshooting this sort of thing it's often helpful to just display the string in the cell (i.e. just the bit inside the `query()` function).  That would have shown up the error quite quickly.